# Hibernate delete record miserably fails

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I've been banging my head against the wall over this.
session.delete(object) miserably fails showing me these messages.

When I copy and paste the delete sql which hibernated generated, and run the sql in SQLDeveloper, it runs just fine and deletes the record but it won't work in hibernate.
weird...
 
I was guessing maybe it's because of "select - before - update" so I put select-before-update="false" in my hbm file but I saw it still issued a select statement before a delete.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
SimpleSystemLogFilter :)

log # 0 at Wed Nov 27 15:37:29 KST 2013 := http://172.16.0.27:9090/sideEffect/properties.do?action=deleteItem&mea_class_no=ggg&grade=1 by test(user# 26)
null
Trying to get method name with param name : action
trying to return method name of : deleteItem
Trying to get method name with param name : action
trying to return method name of : deleteItem
Hibernate: 
    select
        mea_class__.mea_class_no,
        mea_class__.grade,
        mea_class__.HIGHER_CLASS_NO as HIGHER_C3_31_,
        mea_class__.HIGHER_CLASS_GRADE as HIGHER_C4_31_,
        mea_class__.CLASS_LEVEL as CLASS_LE5_31_,
        mea_class__.CLASS_KOR_NAME as CLASS_KO6_31_,
        mea_class__.CLASS_ENG_NAME as CLASS_EN7_31_,
        mea_class__.CLASS_CONT as CLASS_CO8_31_,
        mea_class__.ITEM_GRP_CODE as ITEM_GRP9_31_,
        mea_class__.REGIST_ID as REGIST_10_31_,
        mea_class__.UPDATE_ID as UPDATE_11_31_,
        mea_class__.TRACE_MANAGE_TARGET_YN as TRACE_M12_31_,
        mea_class__.USE_YN as USE_YN13_31_,
        mea_class__.code_age as code_ag14_31_,
        mea_class__.TRACEABILITY as TRACEAB15_31_,
        mea_class__.IS_IN_USE as IS_IN_U16_31_ 
    from
        MEA_CLASS_NO mea_class__ 
    where
        mea_class__.mea_class_no=? 
        and mea_class__.grade=?
15:37:29,946 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - ggg
15:37:29,947 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - 1
15:37:29,950 TRACE BasicExtractor:68 - Found [null] as column [HIGHER_C3_31_]
15:37:29,950 TRACE BasicExtractor:74 - Found [0] as column [HIGHER_C4_31_]
15:37:29,950 TRACE BasicExtractor:74 - Found [1] as column [CLASS_LE5_31_]
15:37:29,950 TRACE BasicExtractor:74 - Found [ggg] as column [CLASS_KO6_31_]
15:37:29,951 TRACE BasicExtractor:74 - Found [ggg] as column [CLASS_EN7_31_]
15:37:29,951 TRACE BasicExtractor:68 - Found [null] as column [CLASS_CO8_31_]
15:37:29,951 TRACE BasicExtractor:68 - Found [null] as column [ITEM_GRP9_31_]
15:37:29,952 TRACE BasicExtractor:68 - Found [null] as column [REGIST_10_31_]
15:37:29,952 TRACE BasicExtractor:68 - Found [null] as column [UPDATE_11_31_]
15:37:29,952 TRACE BasicExtractor:74 - Found [Y] as column [TRACE_M12_31_]
15:37:29,952 TRACE BasicExtractor:74 - Found [Y] as column [USE_YN13_31_]
15:37:29,953 TRACE BasicExtractor:74 - Found [0] as column [code_ag14_31_]
15:37:29,953 TRACE BasicExtractor:74 - Found [1] as column [TRACEAB15_31_]
15:37:29,953 TRACE BasicExtractor:74 - Found [1] as column [IS_IN_U16_31_]
deleteMeaClassNo().jobStat := false
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        JUNC_ITEM_HISTORY 
    where
        mea_class_no=? 
        and grade=?
15:37:29,974 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - ggg
15:37:29,975 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - 1
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        MEA_CLASS_NO 
    where
        mea_class_no=? 
        and grade=?
15:37:29,977 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - ggg
15:37:29,977 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - 1
15:37:29,980  INFO AbstractBatchImpl:195 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
11월 27, 2013 3:37:29 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet springDispatcherServlet threw exception
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3357)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3560)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:480)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at properties.SimplePropertiesDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$707c88a9.deleteMeaClassNo(<generated>)
    at properties.SimplePropertiesDelegate.deleteItem(SimplePropertiesDelegate.java:602)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:471)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:917)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:813)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:798)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at system.log.SimpleSystemLogFilter.doFilter(SimpleSystemLogFilter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at system.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And this is my hbm file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class table="MEA_CLASS_NO"  name="foreign.Mea_class_no" 
    > 
        <composite-id name="compositeKey"  
        class="foreign.MeaClassNoCompositeKey" 
        >
         <key-property name="mea_class_no" />
         <key-property name="grade"/>
    </composite-id>

    <property name="mea_class_no" insert="false" update="false">
     <column name="mea_class_no" />
    </property>

    <many-to-one name="gradeObj" lazy="false" not-found="ignore"
        class="foreign.SimpleForeignGrade" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="grade"></column>
    </many-to-one>

    <property name="grade"  insert="false" update="false">
     <column name="grade"/>
    </property>

    <property name="higher_class_no" >
     <column name="HIGHER_CLASS_NO"/>
    </property>
    <property name="higher_class_grade" >
     <column name="HIGHER_CLASS_GRADE"/>
    </property>
    <property name="class_level">
     <column name="CLASS_LEVEL"/>
    </property>
    <property name="class_kor_name">
     <column name="CLASS_KOR_NAME"/>
    </property>
    <property name="class_eng_name">
     <column name="CLASS_ENG_NAME"/>
    </property>
    <property name="class_cont">
     <column name="CLASS_CONT"/>
    </property>
    <property name="item_grp_code">
     <column name="ITEM_GRP_CODE"/>
    </property>
    <property name="regist_id">
     <column name="REGIST_ID"/>
    </property>

    <property name="update_id">
     <column name="UPDATE_ID"/>
    </property>
    <property name="trace_manage_target_yn">
     <column name="TRACE_MANAGE_TARGET_YN"/>
    </property>
    <!-- regist_ts -->
    <!--  
    <property name="regist_ts" >
     <column name="regist_ts"/>
    </property>
    <property name="update_ts" >
     <column name="update_ts"/>
    </property>
    -->
    <property name="use_yn" >
     <column name="USE_YN"/>
    </property>

    <property name="codeAge" insert="false" update="false">
     <column name="code_age"/>
    </property>

    <!-- 코드 구분 (신코드, 구코드, 자료없음, etc.) -->
    <many-to-one name="code_age" class="properties.item.SimpleItemCodeType"
        lazy="false" not-found="ignore">
        <column name="code_age"></column>
    </many-to-one>

    <!-- 추적관리대상여부 -->
    <many-to-one name="traceability" class="properties.item.SimpleTraceability"
        lazy="false" not-found="ignore">
        <column name="TRACEABILITY"></column>
    </many-to-one>

    <!--  사용여부 -->
    <many-to-one name="isInUse" class="properties.SimpleIsInUse"
        lazy="false" not-found="ignore">
        <column name="IS_IN_USE"></column>
    </many-to-one>

    <!-- 현재 코드에 대한 구품목코드  -->
    <!--  
    <many-to-one name="older_class_no" class="foreign.Mea_class_no"
        lazy="false" not-found="ignore" insert="false" update="false"    >
        <column name="older_class_no"></column>
        <column name="grade"></column>
    </many-to-one>
    -->

    <!-- 이력현황 -->
    <set name="history" cascade="all, persist, delete-orphan, delete" 
        fetch="select"  
        lazy="false" table="JUNC_ITEM_HISTORY">
        <key >
            <column name="mea_class_no"></column>       
            <column name="grade"></column>
        </key>
        <many-to-many not-found="ignore" class="properties.item.SimpleItemHistory"
            column="history_id"
            >
        </many-to-many>     
    </set>  

</class> 
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

EDIT

I just tried this.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Mea_class_no found = readMeaClassNo(target);

        System.out.println("getCurrentLockMode ? " + session.getCurrentLockMode(found));
        session.delete(found);
 System.out.println("isDirty ? " + session.isDirty());
```

and I see this in the console.

```
getCurrentLockMode ? READ
isDirty ? true
```

But I don't know what to do from here.

**EDIT2**
To my surprise, adding

```
optimistic-lock="dirty"
```

to my hbm file, successfully deleted a record but it issued a bizzar delete statement !

```
delete 
    from
        MEA_CLASS_NO 
    where
        mea_class_no=? 
        and grade=? 
        and mea_class_no = ? 
        and grade = ? 
        and grade = ? 
        and HIGHER_CLASS_NO = ? 
        and HIGHER_CLASS_GRADE = ? 
        and CLASS_LEVEL = ? 
        and CLASS_KOR_NAME = ? 
        and CLASS_ENG_NAME = ? 
        and CLASS_CONT = ? 
        and ITEM_GRP_CODE is null 
        and REGIST_ID is null 
        and UPDATE_ID is null 
        and TRACE_MANAGE_TARGET_YN = ? 
        and regist_ts = ? 
        and update_ts = ? 
        and USE_YN = ? 
        and code_age = ? 
        and code_age = ? 
        and TRACEABILITY = ? 
        and IS_IN_USE = ?
16:43:11,747 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - testtt
16:43:11,747 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - 1
16:43:11,747 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - testtt
16:43:11,748 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - 1
16:43:11,748 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - 1
16:43:11,748 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - A06010
16:43:11,748 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - 3
16:43:11,748 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [8] as [INTEGER] - 3
16:43:11,749 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [9] as [VARCHAR] - 테스트트
16:43:11,749 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [10] as [VARCHAR] - testtt
16:43:11,749 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [11] as [VARCHAR] - 테스트트
16:43:11,749 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [12] as [VARCHAR] - Y
16:43:11,750 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [13] as [TIMESTAMP] - 2013-11-15 15:56:24.226544
16:43:11,751 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [14] as [TIMESTAMP] - 2013-11-15 15:56:24.226544
16:43:11,751 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [15] as [VARCHAR] - Y
16:43:11,751 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [16] as [INTEGER] - 1
16:43:11,752 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [17] as [BIGINT] - 1
16:43:11,752 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [18] as [BIGINT] - 1
16:43:11,752 TRACE BasicBinder:84 - binding parameter [19] as [BIGINT] - 1
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11736653/1651233

Comment: @whoAmI, the stacktrace does not mention the StaleStateException.

Comment: Both stacktrace (here and there) have this line: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the reason why it didn't update or delete was a type mismatch.

For some weird reason, table designer declared a numeric column as varchar(1) 
and I was mapping that varchar column to a POJO int field.

Once I changed the field type to String, the issue dissappeard.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a cascade in database schema, causing record to be deleted `MEA_CLASS_NO` every time referencing record is deleted from `JUNC_ITEM_HISTORY`. Or in SQLDeveloper try to run both queries in one transaction. If the cascade exists, you should remove it from database and declare in the Hibernate level.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, but to make the issue easier to be addressed, I removed the association. Still, any update or delete statement fails.

Comment: What did you remove? Foreign key? And did it contain ON DELETE CASCADE? And have you tried to execute both queries in SQLDeveloper?